# can't compile OpenFOAM v1912 with intel icc and intelmpi

Tags: linux, gcc, icc, openfoam, intel-mpi

! UPDATE on 28 Feb, 2020:
The problem is solved. please refer to :https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/issues/1608

#### Summary

I'm new to OpenFOAM and I'm trying to compile OpenFOAM-v1912 using Icc and IntelMPI, only to find the following confusing error. It seems like an error in codes. But it just makes no sense, because I have successfully compiled it with gcc(v4.8.5) and openmpi(1.10.7), *and it worked just fine*. I'd be more than delighted to hear any suggestions. Ideas about what the problem might be will also be of great help. THANKS A LOT!

> wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedParticleTemplates.C(121): error: no operator "==" matches these operands

#### Steps to reproduce

I edited OpenFOAM-v1912/etc/bashrc from

```
...
export WM_COMPILER=Gcc
...
export WM_MPLIB=OPENMPI
...
```

to

```
...
export WM_COMPILER=Icc
...
export WM_MPLIB=INTELMPI
...
```

and I got "ld: cannot find -lmpi" error so I edit OpenFOAM-v1912/wmake/rules/General/Icc/c++

```
CC = icpc -std=c++11
```

to

```
CC = mpiicc -std=c++11
```

then under directory OpenFOAM-v1912/ , I ran

```
./Allwmake
```

#### What I've tried

1. Compiling with $WM_LABEL_SIZE=64

But it just seemed irrelevant and it got stuck on building `libscotch`. Doesn't seem to help at all.

#### Details of the error from the promts:

```
wmake reactingEulerFoam/phaseSystems
wmake reactingEulerFoam/interfacialModels
wmake reactingEulerFoam/interfacialCompositionModels
wmake reactingEulerFoam/derivedFvPatchFields
wmake reactingEulerFoam/reactingMultiphaseEulerFoam/multiphaseSystem
wmake reactingEulerFoam/reactingMultiphaseEulerFoam/multiphaseCompressibleTurbulenceModels
wmake reactingEulerFoam/reactingTwoPhaseEulerFoam/twoPhaseSystem
wmake reactingEulerFoam/reactingTwoPhaseEulerFoam/twoPhaseCompressibleTurbulenceModels
wmake field
mpiicc -std=c++11 -fp-trap=common -fp-model precise -DOPENFOAM=1912 -DWM_DP -DWM_LABEL_SIZE=32 -Wall -Wextra -Wnon-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-unknown-pragmas -diag-disable 327,654,1125,1292,2289,2304,11062,11074,11076 -O3  -DNoRepository -ftemplate-depth-100 -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/finiteVolume/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/fileFormats/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/surfMesh/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/meshTools/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/sampling/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/lagrangian/basic/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/lagrangian/distributionModels/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/basic/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/transportModels -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/transportModels/compressible/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/TurbulenceModels/turbulenceModels/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/TurbulenceModels/incompressible/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/TurbulenceModels/compressible/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/transportModels/compressible/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/basic/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/solidThermo/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/chemistryModel/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/reactionThermo/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/thermophysicalModels/specie/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/fvAgglomerationMethods/pairPatchAgglomeration/lnInclude -IlnInclude -I. -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude -I/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/OSspecific/POSIX/lnInclude   -fPIC -c wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.C -o /share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/build/linux64IccDPInt32Opt/src/functionObjects/field/wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.o
wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedParticleTemplates.C(121): error: no operator "==" matches these operands
            operand types are: Foam::cell == const Foam::label
                  cell() == mesh().faceOwner()[face()]
                         ^
/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/lagrangian/basic/lnInclude/particle.H(70): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
  bool operator==(const particle&, const particle&);
       ^
/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/labelBits.H(123): note: this candidate was rejected because function is not visible
          inline friend bool operator==(const labelBits& a, const labelBits& b)
                             ^
/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/objectMapI.H(85): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
  inline bool Foam::operator==(const objectMap& a, const objectMap& b)
                    ^
/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/OpenFOAM/lnInclude/triFaceI.H(406): note: this candidate was rejected because arguments do not match
  inline bool Foam::operator==(const triFace& a, const triFace& b)
                    ^
(followed by lots of rejected candidates)

            instantiation of "bool Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle::move(TrackCloudType &, Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle::trackingData &, Foam::scalar={Foam::doubleScalar={double}}) [with TrackCloudType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticleCloud]" at line 212 of "/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/lagrangian/basic/lnInclude/Cloud.C"
            instantiation of "void Foam::Cloud<ParticleType>::move(TrackCloudType &, ParticleType::trackingData &, Foam::scalar={Foam::doubleScalar={double}}) [with ParticleType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle, TrackCloudType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticleCloud]" at line 275 of "wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.C"

wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedParticleTemplates.C(138): error: no operator "=" matches these operands
            operand types are: Foam::cell = Foam::label
                  cell() = nbrCelli;
                         ^
          detected during:
            instantiation of "bool Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle::move(TrackCloudType &, Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle::trackingData &, Foam::scalar={Foam::doubleScalar={double}}) [with TrackCloudType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticleCloud]" at line 212 of "/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/src/lagrangian/basic/lnInclude/Cloud.C"
            instantiation of "void Foam::Cloud<ParticleType>::move(TrackCloudType &, ParticleType::trackingData &, Foam::scalar={Foam::doubleScalar={double}}) [with ParticleType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticle, TrackCloudType=Foam::wallBoundedStreamLineParticleCloud]" at line 275 of "wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.C"

compilation aborted for wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.C (code 2)
make: *** [/share/software/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1912-ICC/build/linux64IccDPInt32Opt/src/functionObjects/field/wallBoundedStreamLine/wallBoundedStreamLine.o] Error 2
```

#### Environment information

- OpenFOAM: v1912 (codes from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openfoam/files/v1912/OpenFOAM-v1912.tgz)
- ThirdParty from https://sourceforge.net/projects/openfoam/files/v1912/ThirdParty-v1912.tgz
- Intel suite: parallel_studio_xe_2020_cluster_edition
- Intel icc: icc (ICC) 19.1.0.166 20191121
- Intel MPI lib: for Linux* OS, Version 2019 Update 6 Build 20191024
- OS Kernel: Linux version 3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64  (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) )
- OS: CentOS 7.7.1908
- CPU: 72 * Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240 CPU @ 2.60GHz

## Solution

The problem is solved! Please refer to https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/issues/1608.

Comment: Did you check out this web page that  provides instructions on compiling OpenFOAM with Intel MPI - versions are different but maybe the step are comparable? https://linuxcluster.wordpress.com/2018/06/04/compiling-openfoam-5-with-intel-mpi/

Comment: Better yet - Recipe: Compile OpenFOAM* with Intel® Compiler for Intel® Xeon® Scalable Processors: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/recipe-compile-openfoam-with-intel-compiler-for-intel-xeon-scalable-processors

Comment: THANK YOU for suggestions! I got help from the OpenFOAM-v1912 developers.

Comment: @YipZLF, you should move your solution as an accepted answer to your own question. Helps others see that this is fixed.